# no se implemento select2 en laravel

Tags: laravel, select2

soy nuevo en laravel quiero implementar select2 para un select multiple pero no me deja, ni lee los estilos css si entro al codigo fuente de la pagina y reviso los enlaces del css y js minificados si me aparecen bien al entrar en la consola me marca en la colsola del navegador jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.

```js
  $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
```

```html
     <!--CDN en el orden que lo tengo en mi pagina en -->   
     
  <!--  <script src="{{asset('js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js')}}"></script>-->
  <!--  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>-->
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <!--  <script src="{{asset('js/main.js')}}"></script>-->
    
    <form action="">

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">


</form>
```

[image: error consola]

[image: resultado del codigo]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow!. Si quieres obtener respuestas, es mucho mejor copiar y pegar el código en vez de las imágenes, además de no estar bien visto, normas del sitio. Puedes vera el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: @RogerTorné Gracias, ya corregiré eso

Comment: ¿Haz puesto el código de select2 dentro de $(document).ready()?

Comment: Si, si lo coloque dentro del document. Ready